# Why am I getting an exception when trying to debug my Jasmine test (they run just fine)?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, jasmine, resharper, phantomjs

I have some unit tests that are very very simple to test my angular controller.  When I run them, they execute successfully; however, when I try to debug them, I get an exception.

I am running VS 2013, with AngularJS 1.2, ReSharper 8.2, Jasmine 1.3, and PhantomJS 1.9.7.

Here is my very simple controller:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("PermutedMultiples", []);

    function mainController($scope) {
        $scope.answer = -1;
        $scope.N = 0;

    }

    app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", mainController]);
})();
```

Here is the simple test suite:

```
///<reference path="/Scripts/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="/Scripts/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="/Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="/Scripts/app/MainController.js"/>

describe("Main controller tests.", function () {
    var scope;

    beforeEach(module("PermutedMultiples"));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller("MainController", { $scope: scope });
    }));

    it("Answer should be initialized to -1", function() {
        expect(scope.answer).toBe(-1);
    });

    it("N should be initialized to 0", function() {
        expect(scope.N).toBe(0);
    });

})
```

Like I said:  both tests run just fine, but when I try to debug into them, I get an ObjectDisposedException exception.

I write my tests, then I write the code to make the tests pass.  When the test doesn't pass after I have written my code, I like to be able to debug through my code to figure out where the problem is.  Can someone please help me figure out if I've done something wrong here?